# Is there any way to target the plain JavaScript object type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.1

#### UPDATE 2021

For a working solution using newer features see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59647842/1323504

---

I'm trying to write a function where I'd like to indicate that it returns *some kind of* plain JavaScript object. The object's signature is unknown, and not interesting for now, only the fact that it's a plain object. I mean a plain object which satisfies for example jQuery's `isPlainObject` function. For example

```
{ a: 1, b: "b" }
```

is a plain object, but

```
var obj = new MyClass();
```

is not a "plain" object, as its `constructor` is not `Object`. jQuery does some more precise job in `$.isPlainObject`, but that's out of the question's scope.

If I try to use `Object` type, then it will be compatible to any custom object's too, as they're inherited from `Object`.

Is there a way to target the "plain object" type in TypeScript?

I would like a *type*, which would satisfy this for example.

```
var obj: PlainObject = { a: 1 }; // perfect
var obj2: PlainObject = new MyClass(); // compile-error: not a plain object
```

**Use case**

I have kind of a strongly-typed stub for server-side methods, like this. These stubs are generated by one of my code generators, based on ASP.NET MVC controllers.

```
export class MyController {
  ...
  static GetResult(id: number): JQueryPromise<PlainObject> {
    return $.post("mycontroller/getresult", ...);
  }
  ...
}
```

Now when I call it in a consumer class, I can do something like this.

```
export class MyViewModelClass {
  ...
  LoadResult(id: number): JQueryPromise<MyControllerResult> { // note the MyControllerResult strong typing here
    return MyController.GetResult(id).then(plainResult => new MyControllerResult(plainResult));
  }
  ...
}
```

And now imagine that the controller method returns `JQueryPromise<any>` or `JQueryPromise<Object>`. And now also imagine that by accident I write `done` instead of `then`. Now I have a hidden error, because the viewmodel method will not return the correct promise, but I won't get a compile-error.

If I had this imaginary `PlainObject` type, I'd expect to get a compile error stating that `PlainObject` cannot be converted to `MyControllerResult`, or something like that.

Comment: could you give us an example of what you'd like to return?

Comment: Thank you, added some further clarifications

Comment: In the end this means you'll pretty much accept `any` value, since pretty much everything in Javascript is an object and you don't even care about any specific characteristics of it. The caller of your function may decide to implement your desired object as a class for their own purposes; the resulting object will still be perfectly compatible with your expected "plain" object, especially if you don't even really care about anything about that object. While an interesting question, I somewhat fail to see the practicality of it.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the good comment, in theory you're right. I need it for a specific use-case. I need it for a method which returns a `promise` of an AJAX call, and I want to indicate that the promise value is a plain object (parsed by `JSON.parse` for example), and not any instance of any class. So I'd use it as an *output* type, not an *input*.

Comment: You typically type hint to enforce specific characteristics of an object; why exactly are you trying to type hint for the *absence* of specific characteristics? It shouldn't *really* matter whether the method returns a class or not, that's an implementation detail. As long as that class instance still conforms to the expected behaviour, which in this case is `any`, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Do you expect the result of that AJAX call to have a consistent layout? As in, could you describe the results as a type even though there isn't a constructor?

Comment: I've updated the post with my detailed example use-case

Comment: Presumably, `MyControllerResult` still expects `plainResult` to have certain properties, right? Why don't you create a type definition for that?

Comment: @MikeC The assignment happens dynamically at runtime (like jQuery's `extend`), and I don't want to kind of duplicate the layout of `MyControllerResult`. Actually `MyControllerResult` is a `knockoutjs` viewmodel.

Comment: Last attempt: the type system allows for inheritance and *sub classes* of the hinted type are equally accepted. Since `any` object will be a sub class of "a plain object", this type hint, if it existed, won't be able to enforce very much.

Comment: What _might_ work in your case is requiring an object with an explicitly defined [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/index-signatures.html). This will require the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option. Any class or interface that does not explicitly implement the index signature will be rejected by TypeScript, although I believe `Object` is one of them (thus you'll need to modify the native type lib).

Comment: @deceze Sorry but I don't get your points. There is nothign like `any` in the use-case example code.

Comment: I keep using `any` half as a pun, and half as a hint that that may be the only real type applicable here. :)

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Here's the thing: types are used to enforce contracts. If you don't have a specific contract, then you can't expect to statically enforce the typing. However, again, since `MyControllerResult` requires the object to have *some specific* properties, you should document those then use that as your type. I fail to see how `PlainObject` is useful here.

Comment: how about something like this?https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20getResult%3CT%3E(id%3A%20number)%3A%20Promise%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve('T'%20as%20any)%3B%20%2F%2F%20actual%20call%20here%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyExpectedResult%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Builder%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(result%3A%20MyExpectedResult)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AgetResult(5).then((result%3A%20MyExpectedResult)%20%3D%3E%20new%20Builder(result))%3B

Comment: I do have a contract, the contract that it should be a *plain* object, meaning that it's constructor is `Object`. This is a pretty well defined contract in my opinion. See this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pyd466tb/

Comment: @ZoltánTamási It's really not. You're only stating that it should be an `Object` but that doesn't tell you anything about the kind of data you're expecting. Please explain to me why defining your contract based on the kind of data you're going to receive (i.e., what properties you expect the object to have) is a bad idea. Right now it seems like you're just focused on applying your flawed idea rather than correcting your approach.

Comment: I misused the word "contract", sorry. It's indeed not literally a *contract*, but it's a kind of type restriction  Generally it's of course not a bad idea in any sense to enuemrate the properties, I just want to omit that, because it's irrelevant in my code, as I have dynamic mappings from these plain results. Some of the web API results have really complex structure, what I already have defined in the strongly-typed viewmodel classes, I wouldn't like to duplicate them

Comment: Okay, thank you guys for your constructive ideas, I think the end result is that it's simply not possible, so I'll rethink it.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási If you've already defined it for your viewmodels, why not just change those descriptions to an interface and have your viewmodels use that interface? Then there's no duplication, you just say that both the viewmodel and the AJAX data use the same interface.

Comment: @MikeC There is a code duplication, because I have to build the interface with the same property names as my viewmodel. But indeed, that would be the most robust and theoretically correct approach, you're right. I just wouldn't make use of it anywhere. I just need the fact that the return type is a plain object :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tested in TypeScript 3.7.2:

For a flat plain object, you can do:

```js
type Primitive =
  | bigint
  | boolean
  | null
  | number
  | string
  | symbol
  | undefined;

type PlainObject = Record<string, Primitive>;

class MyClass {
  //
}

const obj1: PlainObject = { a: 1 }; // Works
const obj2: PlainObject = new MyClass(); // Error
```

For a nested plain object:

```js
type Primitive =
  | bigint
  | boolean
  | null
  | number
  | string
  | symbol
  | undefined;

type JSONValue = Primitive | JSONObject | JSONArray;

interface JSONObject {
  [key: string]: JSONValue;
}

interface JSONArray extends Array<JSONValue> { }

const obj3: JSONObject = { a: 1 }; // Works
const obj4: JSONObject = new MyClass(); // Error

const obj5: JSONObject = { a: { b: 1 } }; // Works
const obj6: JSONObject = { a: { b: { c: 1 } } }; // Works
const obj7: JSONObject = { a: { b: { c: { d: 1 } } } }; // Works
```

Code is an adaptation from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496#issuecomment-128553540

For primitives, see [mdn web docs > Primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive).

---

An alternative solution would be to use a library [sindresorhus / type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) or use the implementation from it found here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/basic.d.ts.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, sorry for not noticing it so long. This is indeed a better approach using the up-to-date feature.

Comment: Note that `symbol` is not a part of JSON.

Comment: This is MISLEADING. It appears to achieve the intended but it works for a totally different reason.

Typescript auto adds the index signature `[key: string]: ...` for type aliases (object literals) and that makes them assignable to `JSONObject` (has the aforementioned signature).

Broken:
`interface X { a: number; } const x: X = { a: 1 }; const obj: JSONObject = x;` DOES NOT WORK even though it IS a plain object. And also broken:
`class MyClass {} interface MyClass { [k: string]: JSONValue; } const obj: JSONObject = new MyClass();` WORKS even though it IS NOT a plain object

Answer (score 8):

In my code I have something similiar to what you're asking:

```
export type PlainObject = { [name: string]: any }
export type PlainObjectOf<T> = { [name: string]: T }
```

And I also have a type guard for that:

```
export function isPlainObject(obj: any): obj is PlainObject {
    return obj && obj.constructor === Object || false;
}
```

---

#### Edit

Ok, I understand what you're looking for, but unfortunately that is not possible.
If i understand you correctly then this is what you're after:

```
type PlainObject = {
    constructor: ObjectConstructor;
    [name: string]: any
}
```

The problem is that in 'lib.d.ts' [Object](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L98) is defined like so:

```
interface Object {
    /** The initial value of Object.prototype.constructor is the standard built-in Object constructor. */
    constructor: Function;

    ...
}
```

And then this:

```
let o: PlainObject = { key: "value" };
```

Results with an error:

```
Type '{ key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'PlainObject'.
  Types of property 'constructor' are incompatible.
    Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'ObjectConstructor'.
      Property 'getPrototypeOf' is missing in type 'Function'.
```

Comment: The problem is that an assignment like `var obj: {[index:string]: any} = new MyControllerResult()` is still accepted by the compiler using TS2.1. It might be related to `noImplicitAny`, I don't have that option, and I can't even turn it for in the current codebase.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Every object in js is a "PlainObject", a class instance is also a plain object.  It similar to doing: `class A {}` then `class B extends A {}` and `let a: A = new B()`.

Comment: No, a *plain* object is plain in the sens that it's not an instance of a "custom" class. In your code you're checking exactly that. But a type-guard is not a type hint unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, exactly that.. thank you for pointing out the key. Do you have any idea why it is defined so? I mean why isn't the `Object.constructor` defined  as `ObjectConstructor`?

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out I guess. It needs to be a `Function` to allow any class instance to still be an `Object`.

Comment: Well, that's actually a good question. In js functions are objects, and it even states in the comment above the `constructor` that this is the case (updated the comment in my answer). I'm not sure why then this isn't the case in the `lib.d.ts` file. Maybe there are reasons for it that I'm unaware of.  Maybe this calls for posting an issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134800/discussion-between-zoltan-tamasi-and-nitzan-tomer).

Comment: Here is the related TS ticket: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13866

Comment: Keep in mind that this `PlainObject` type will incorrectly report that arrays are plain objects. This was unexpected to me, and I opened an issue about it - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24083.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this to work in TS 4.9:

```
type PlainObject = Record<string, {}>;

class MyClass {}

function test(one: PlainObject) {}
test({ a: 1, b: "a", c: new MyClass() }); // OK
test(1); // Error
test("a"); // Error
test([1, 2, 3]); // Error
test(new Date()); // Error
test(new Map()); // Error
test(new Set()); // Error
test(new MyClass()); // Error
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQwJYDsDyAjAVhAxsKAXigCU8B7AJwBMAeAZ2EtQHMAaKAbwF8A+AbgBQg3Inr0oAWRABhMRJ7CAZgFcU+JORRRgERgAotEAFyxEqTDnwBKLt0G6DnKAlMBGDhlMAiBN464pigQAO5SsvL6ttzW-FAA9PFQaADSDnrA+m6xCUkAopSUVOkGvt45iVAFRZQlmQDaHlAATBwAzAC6FfmFxY6ZwWEAIgi6Ud1VvbX9+oNSCGDjcZXVfRmzoVAAyhCZ1hOr0+tz0nII4ku5kzVAA)

The difference with the accepted answer is that it also allows the plain object to contain complex values, and not only primitives:

```js
type ObjectOfPrimitives = Record<string, Primitive>;

function test(one: ObjectOfPrimitives) {}

test({ 
  a: 1, 
  b: "a", 
  c: new MyClass(), // Error: Type 'MyClass' is not assignable to type 'ObjectOfPrimitives'.
});
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvAKClAHygCMEBzBAO2D0JIHt6AbCAQ0tqMoFcmnOoPJMQhwBAZ2CJKZCSGHMB3SgBMIAMyoQVAbhw5QkKAHliAKwgBjYMfXxkqDBHFQsUAEpX6cFQB5J0mQANLCIKGiYAHx6OJZMrOIuALIgAMLxiQDeAL766srWCPSUUMDOwAAUxRAAXCbmVjZ2YY6Y4gCUUDn6ZZIVmVC0rHUAjCG0xHUARKxT4-iWdZQQAO5QKekJ4hXtIQD0e1AAonBw3nUAKuDQAOQbGeI3UAgulPTAUFvklKzELKX0UrXKA3UwWay2ezhJyPAB0OGy7R0UCAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can try recursive type (naive solution)

```
type SerializableObject = { [x: string]: SerializableObject | number | string | [] };
```

Not good, not terrible :)