# Conditional types for objects with constructors

Tags: typescript, constructor, immutable.js

When I use Immutable.js I use some custom types I've written to make my life a little easier.  One of these predicts if a property of an Immutable map is going to be gotten in its original state (primitive) or as another Immutable map.  I achieve this with the following conditional type:

```
type ImmutablePrimitive = string | number | boolean | symbol | String | Number | Boolean | Symbol | Element;

type ImmutablePrimitiveSwitchValue<VALUE_TYPE> = VALUE_TYPE extends ImmutablePrimitive ? VALUE_TYPE : Immutable.Map<any, any>;
```

`ImmutablePrimitiveSwitch` checks to see if the type being passed to it is named in a small list of primitive types - if it is that type is used, otherwise a generic map is returned.

This works well in **most** cases but isn't how Immutable actually works.  Under the hood Immutable has a concept of "plain" objects, [that are defined as objects that do not have constructors](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/40efbc31f7abcd9c26d714c9b5af0ba03b4dfcaa/src/utils/isPlainObj.js#L11).

**Can Typescript perform a similar check in conditional types?**  I'd love to be able to replace my incomplete list of literals with a proper check that matches Immutable's logic.

Comment: `ternaried`?  `ternary'd`? Types with a ternary operator?  whatever...

Comment: These are called conditional types.

Comment: @SLaks updated.

Comment: Unfortunately you can not. Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027864/is-there-any-way-to-target-the-plain-javascript-object-type-in-typescript#answer-42028363